# What is the best full screen background image size for Retina display?

Tags: html, css, background-image, retina-display

I'm working on the site with difficult background image. And I don't know what size I need to use for background image? Big size or background-size: cover.

What is the best full screen background image size for Retina display?

Comment: There are many Retina displays, some for Mac, some for iPad and some for iPhone. Which are you referring to?

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn, for all devices. Mac, for example.

Comment: @Milche Patern, thank you. I know this. I'm asking about full screen on Mac.

Comment: "retina display" is a marketing term that refers to having a high-enough pixel density that the human eye can't make out individual pixels. It's **NOT** a screen size. You're asking for the equivalent of "do I need 1024x768 or 1280x1024?", but asking for "retina display" is more like "Do I want 300dpi or 600dpi".

Comment: @MarcB got it. My English and my something else :). I mean what image size I need to use on Mac. For example,http://www.zara.com/ uses image(http://static.zara.net/static/2013/I/homes/WOMAN_31.jpg) with width - 2880px.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to Retina Display, it means twice the size of normal resolution.

Comment: I know. My question about the best size for Imac with Retina. 2000px or 4000px or ...?

Comment: @Milche Patern, thank you. 2000px with background-size: cover; background-width: 100%?